# Bug? NotebookDirectory[] crashes frontend in case of external kernel

Tags: bugs, crash, remote-access

**Bug introduced in 11.2.0**

---

Calling `NotebookDirectory[]` on a remote machine crashes Mathematica. I do understand that calling `NotebookDirectory[]` should return $failed, as the remote is not capable of locating my local Notebook. I tested this on multiple local machines and in all cases resulted in a Mathematica crash. Is this a (known) bug?

**Remote Kernel**
Linux Mathematica 11.1

**Local**
Windows 8.1, Mathematica 11.2

*Note that using Mathematica 11.1 on the local machine does not result in a crash*

Comment: I am tagging this as "bugs" because I can reproduce it with a 11.2.0 front end on OS X, but not with a 11.0.1 or 11.1.1 front end. Please report it to Wolfram.  With an older front end, it simply returns the notebook path on the local machine (not `$Failed`). This is not usable on the remote machine, of course.

Comment: reported at Wolfram